# Twilio & posting to external API --- Import Statement Error

Tags: twilio-api, android-glide

BLUF, I'm getting a "Cannot use import statement outside a module" error trying to run a Twilio function. I have the dependency installed in my function and I've tried adding a "require" statement in the code but I seem to get errors no matter what I do. I'm sure this is a basic misunderstanding on my part, but I can't wrap my head around it...

Context:

I have successfully been logging inbound SMS messages to Google Sheets for some time via this template: https://www.twilio.com/code-exchange/log-incoming-text-messages-in-google-sheets.

But I need to update the integration to my app. I'm using Glide Apps and here's their API template:

```
import * as glide from "@glideapps/tables";

const callLogzTable = glide.table({
    token: "*********************",
    app: "xxx",
    table: "xxx",
    columns: {
        to: { type: "string", name: "Name" },
        from: { type: "string", name: "Skqwe" },
        date: { type: "date-time", name: "cuKHr" },
        body: { type: "string", name: "HTuJb" },
        image: { type: "image-uri", name: "paart" }
    }
});

const callLogzID = await callLogzTable.addRow({
    // Add columns here
});
```

Here's the full code I built and remember, I have a dependancy for @glideapps/tables=* as well. I was expecting any inbound sms to be added to the table as a new row.

```
const { glide } = require("@glideapps/tables");
const Twilio = require("twilio");

const callLogzTable = glide.table({
  token: "xxx",
  app: "xxx",
  table: "xxx",
  columns: {
    to: { type: "string", name: "Name" },
    from: { type: "string", name: "Skqwe" },
    date: { type: "date-time", name: "cuKHr" },
    body: { type: "string", name: "HTuJb" },
    image: { type: "image-uri", name: "paart" }
  }
});

exports.handler = async (context, event, callback) => {
  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();

  try {
    const timestamp = new Date().toISOString(); // get the current timestamp

    const callLogzID = await callLogzTable.addRow({
      columns: {
        to: event.to,
        from: event.from,
        date: timestamp,
        body: event.body,
        image: event.mediaURL
      }
    });

    callback(null, twiml);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === 404) {
      console.error('Not Found.');
    } else if (
      error.code === 400 &&
      error.errors &&
      error.errors[0] &&
      error.errors[0].message
    ) {
      console.error(`Post error: ${error.errors[0].message}.`);
    } else {
      console.error(`Integration error: ${error.message || error}`);
    }

    twiml.message('Error. Please try again later.');
    callback(null, twiml);
  }
};
```

Thank you for the assist!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a version of the library (an older version) that doesn't export an ES module, as Functions doesn't support ES modules.